Cannot bind program to OpenVPN interface to use VPN
I have my Ubuntu 22.04 server setup with an OpenVPN client, I only want one program on this server to use the OpenVPN network. To prevent all traffic from automatically getting routed through the vpn I added pull-filter ignore "redirect-gateway" & pull-filter ignore "bypass-dhcp" ovpn options.
Many programs have the ability to bind to a specific IP/interface, I figured doing this would route that traffic through the vpn. However I can't send any traffic when doing this. For example ping -I 10.33.0.10 google.com would attempt to ping google.com through the vpn interface with IP 10.33.0.10.
My OpenVPN client config, running OpenVPN 2.5.9 on Ubuntu 22.04. I'm connecting to a remote VPN service, I don't have access to the server config. I can set one up if further experimenting is required.
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote remote.server 1195
remote-cert-tls server
auth SHA256
key-direction 1
setenv CLIENT_CERT 0

pull-filter ignore "redirect-gateway"
pull-filter ignore "bypass-dhcp"

<tls-auth>
-snip-
</tls-auth>
resolv-retry infinite
ignore-unknown-option block-outside-dns ncp-disable
cipher AES-128-GCM
auth-user-pass
ncp-disable
tun-mtu-extra 32

<ca>
-snip-
</ca>

I feel like I'm missing something obvious, but I've searched up and down trying to find a thread with a similar issue but I can't find a solution. I found one thread, but it went no where.
Edit: I found the ping command can do what I want if use the interface name e.g. ping -I tun0 google.com. Unfortunately not all programs work with interfaces, I need the ability to bind the program to the interface's IP.
Edit2: After more digging I found a thread very similar to mine that almost works. The solution allows for outbound connections by binding the IP, however inbound connections are very hit or miss.
I ended up applying (my local IP for the vpn keeps changing, ignore that):
ip route add 10.33.0.0/24 dev tun0 src 10.33.0.81 table rt_tunnel
ip route add default via 10.33.0.1 dev tun0 table rt_tunnel

ip rule add from 10.33.0.81/32 table rt_tunnel
ip rule add to 10.33.0.81/32 table rt_tunnel

iptables -A INPUT -i tun0 -p tcp --dport 51412 -j ACCEPT

Using the ping -I 10.33.0.81 google.com command works, speedtest from Ookla also has a bind to IP feature but that doesn't work as well, it spits out some bind errors. As a substitute I've been using iperf3. The main program I was hoping to use this for is qBittorrent, it has options for both interface and IP, however it requires inbound connections. Technically this issue may be solved, but I'm not sure where the problem lies with the inbound connections.

"Many programs have the ability to bind to a specific IP/interface"...maybe. Mostly this is the case for services (things that listen for incoming connections). It's much less common for tools making outbound connections. What software specifically are you hoping to use with the VPN? This sounds like something that would be better resolved with appropriate routing rules.

I don't think binding an interface means that you don't need a route that covers the destination, let alone binding a source IP doesn't work quite the same IIRC. Note that on Linux you can have "duplicate" routes with different metrics. (But you do want to avoid the alternative routes that "def1" configures.)

@larsks I updated the original thread with more information. ||
TomYan I was unsure was def1 was so I removed it from the ignore command, should I add that back?

Through persistence and stubbornness I have solved my problem, by constantly making changes until something worked. My issue was routing, the interface was not routed properly to allow me to utilize the bind feature on most programs. Of course I barely understand what the route commands do, but they work. The thread I found here describes the solution.
From the post

You need to set up an additional routing table for that interface.
I assume that your tunnel has ip address 10.10.0.10, subnet
255.255.255.0 and gateway 10.10.0.1.

Edit /etc/iproute2/rt_tables and add a new routing table with name
rt_tunnel and preference 1 at the end
1  rt_tunnel

Configure the routing table. We add the reachable network and its
default gateway
ip route add 10.10.0.0/24 dev tun0 src 10.10.0.10 table rt_tunnel
ip route add default via 10.10.0.1 dev tun0 table rt_tunnel

Add routing rules, so the system know when to use the new routing
table
ip rule add from 10.10.0.10/32 table rt_tunnel
ip rule add to 10.10.0.10/32 table rt_tunnel



After applying these settings and some other route changes for my specific setup, I'm able to get ~50MB/s down using qBittorrent through the VPN.
